# Adding an image to the JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

I want to add an Image to the JFrame, the `add( )` method is generating an error which says "cannot find symbol: method add(JLabel)" ... How can I fix that?

** I still haven't called the `ImageLoading( )` method from the main method.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class NetworkingGame {

NetworkingGame(){
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Angry Painters");
    jfrm.setSize(800, 480);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);

}

public void ImageLoading(){
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("angry-painters.jpg");
    JLabel jl = new JLabel(i);
    add(jl); //The error is in this line
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            new NetworkingGame();
        }
    });

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visibility of `JFrame jfrm` is limited by constructor of `NetworkingGame`. So `add` method does not exist in `NetworkingGame`. Make your `JFrame` member of `NetworkingGame`.

```
public class NetworkingGame {
    private JFrame jfrm;

    NetworkingGame(){
        jfrm = new JFrame("Angry Painters");


    ...

        JLabel jl = new JLabel(i);
        jfrm.add(jl);
```

Comment: It worked thanks :) Any idea why the image doesn't load? although there aren't any errors!

Comment: @InspiringProgramming Not sure, maybe path mismatch.

Comment: should I write the whole path or just place the image in the directory and call it by its name like above?

Comment: @InspiringProgramming, are you using Eclipse? Where you put image now?

Comment: In the `classes` folder ... I'm using netbeans.

Comment: how will I call the method `ImageLoading( )` from the main function? in the `run( )` method or outside of it?

Comment: @InspiringProgramming, please make another question.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you should write

```
jfrm.add(jl);
```

and have `jfrm` as a member.

In you case you really calling `this.add()` which is not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the `add` method as if it was an instance method in your class `NetworkingGame`   and your class doesn't have any method, so you are getting the compiler error as the compiler can't find any method of such a name in your class `NetworkingGame`, so add it to the Jframe instead.

```
NetworkingGame(){
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Angry Painters");
    jfrm.setSize(800, 480);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("angry-painters.jpg");
    JLabel jl = new JLabel(i);
    jfrm.add(jl);
}
```